# Express router post function not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Declaration:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
```

Route.js: Post call here

```
router.route('/signup')
    .post(function (req, res) {
        console.log('post signup called', req.body);
        res.json({message: 'signup'});
    });

module.exports = router;
```

The `req.body` is always undefined. I am able to print them console inside ajax call. I don't understand `req.body` is undefined. What am I missing?

Ajax post data sent like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/signup',
    type: 'POST',
    data: params,
    success: function (res) {
        console.log('res', res);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
    }
});
```

server js: Already using `body-parser` here

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var request = require("request");
var router = require('./app/routes/route.js');
var functions = require('./app/functions/functions.js');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var model = require('./app/model/model.js');

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public_html'));
app.use('/', router);
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '5mb', extended: false }));
```

Comment: You need to use [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) in your Express server.

Comment: @robertklep I am already using body parser

Comment: @robertklep doing that as well

Comment: Finally we're getting somewhere :)

Answer (score 5):

Your requests won't be passed through `body-parser` because you're declaring it *after* the router (Express passes requests through middleware and routes in order of declaration; if a request can be handled by `router`, it won't be passed through the `body-parser` middleware anymore):

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public_html'));
app.use('/', router);
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '5mb', extended: false }));
```

If you move `body-parser` to the front, it should work better:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public_html'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '5mb', extended: false }));
app.use('/', router);
```

Comment: Thank you. didn't realise that.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use body-parser

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

```
express.use(bodyParser.json());
```